# External CSS in Flying Saucer

Tags: java, css, flying-saucer

I would like to know how to include the External CSS in Flying-Saucer.Before that *THB* I checked with all the available links in `StackOverflow` but they are not helpful.That's the reason why made this one my self.

`TestCSS.xhtml` renamed version of `TestCSS.html`.So content of them are same.
Below (Image 1 ) is the Structure of my Project  in Eclipse IDE.If I run the TestCSS.html it will give the page result as Image 2 in Browser.

***Below are Code which are not working as External CSS :***

```
This one Working :
<style>
.redFontClass
{
  color : red;
}
.blueFontClass
{
  color : blue;
}
</style>

This one NOT Working :
<link href="RedCSS.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

This one NOT Working :
<link rel="stylesheet" 
href="http://localhost:8888/Fly-Sauccer-Web/css/RedCSS.css" type="text/css" />

This one NOT Working :
<link href="file:///C:/Users/Joseph.M/WorkPlace_Struts2/Fly-Sauccer-Web/WebContent/css/RedCSS.css"  rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

I tried with all the ways including absolute path of css inside of the xhtml also.but css is not getting applied.Please help me to fix the problem.

***Image 1***

[image]

***Image 2***

[image]

***RedCSS.css***

```
.fontClass
{
  color : red;
}
```

***TestCSS.html***

```
<html>
<head>
<link href="file:///C:/Users/Joseph.M/WorkPlace_Struts2/Fly-Sauccer-Web/WebContent/css/RedCSS.css"  rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
<b>This Should come assss <span class = "fontClass" >Red</span> </b>
</body>
</html>
```

**Java Code :**

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{

    // Path of Input File 
    String inputFile = "C:\\Users\\Joseph.M\\WorkPlace_Struts2\\Fly-Sauccer-Web\\WebContent\\TestCSS.xhtml";
    // Path of Output File 
    String outputFile = "C:\\Users\\Joseph.M\\WorkPlace_Struts2\\Fly-Sauccer-Web\\output.pdf";
    OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);             
    ITextRenderer renderer = new ITextRenderer();

    DocumentBuilder builder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
    InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(new File(inputFile)));
    Document doc = builder.parse(is);
    is.close();
    renderer.setDocument(doc,null);        
    renderer.layout();
    renderer.createPDF(os);             
    os.close();
}
```

Comment: Hey have you checked if the css is loaded properly? If yes you could do `color:red !important;`.

Comment: Please explain, what you mean by "css is loaded".How could I  check  css is loaded or not in java .That is possible in Web alone.there I didn't face any problem.Proble with PDF generation in Java Code.

Comment: Looking at your project structure, shouldn't the href be `css/RedCSS.css`?

Comment: Thanks for reply.I tried that too but no use.

Answer (score 0):

Given the structure of the project, `<link href="css/RedCSS.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />` should definitely work.

Here is a working sample :

File struct :

[image]

File 1 : `testRed.html`

```
<html>
<head>
    <link href="css/testRed.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
    Should be <b class="redFontClass">red</b>
</body>
</html>
```

File 2 : `css/testRed.css`

```
.redFontClass {color : red;}
```

Java code :

```
  String inputFile = "testRed.html";
  String outputFile = "testRed.pdf";
  OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
  ITextRenderer renderer = new ITextRenderer();

  DocumentBuilder builder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
  InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(new File(inputFile)));
  Document doc = builder.parse(is);
  is.close();
  renderer.setDocument(doc, null);
  renderer.layout();
  renderer.createPDF(os);
  os.close();
```

Comment: Thanks for reply,but it seems not working.Could you give me folder structure for all the files you mentioned ?

Comment: I added a screenshot of my java project in the response.

Comment: It is not working for me. could you give me your email id ? I will send the zip file where you can find error.

Comment: You'd better upload it on a public file server and add the link in the question.

Answer (score 0):

I tried an similar thing on my localmachine and i tried it with the solution of obourgain

    `<link href="css/testRed.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />`

The response for this way was 302 which means that the resource was found with redirecting but the result of this get was empty.
When i add a / before css all works fine.

    `<link href="/css/testRed.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />`

Answer (score 0):

I use the "classpath" keyword in a Spring Boot environment.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" th:href="@{classpath:templates/style.css}"/>
```

worked for me.

I hope this helps someone with a Spring Boot + Thymeleaf + Flying Saucer setup.

Comment: Please explain why it worked for you, and why it should work for others. Random coincidence is not good enough reason to exhume a post from 4 years ago.

Comment: it is not working for Spring Boot + Thymeleaf + Flying Saucer setup. run time error: "org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Link base "classpath:css/pdfexport.css" cannot be context relative (/) or page relative unless you implement the org.thymeleaf.context.IWebContext interface (context is of class: org.thymeleaf.context.Context) (offerDetailsPDFTemplate:5)
 "

Answer (score 0):

Recently I faced a similar problem: it turned out that the CSS file was in a different encoding. You may have the same problem. First, you need to find out the encoding of the file:

```
file -i <my css file>
```

And then convert it into UTF-8:

```
iconv -f <my css file enconding> -t UTF-8 <my css file> > <my css file in utf-8>
```

In my case, after converting from UTF-16 to UTF-8, a PDF file has been generated.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer this link. https://web.archive.org/web/20150905173204/http://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2007/06/26/generating-pdfs-with-flying-saucer-and-itext.html

Its mentioned that when you want to use an external css file, you should have a media="print" attribute on the link tag.

link href="file:///C:/Users/Joseph.M/WorkPlace_Struts2/Fly-Sauccer-Web/WebContent/css/RedCSS.css"  rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="print"

Answer (score 0):

For me, I just did exactly what [Wolf359](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53198036/159652) did:

A lil bit of detail, this is my html template:

```
<link th:href="@{classpath:/css/styles.css}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

And in the Spring Boot project under the `src/main/resources` folder, I have

```
src/main/resources
|
|── css/
|   |── styles.css
|   |
. . . . .
```

It works like a charm!