# XHTML to Docx conversion using docx4j not reading font-size style

Tags: docx4j, xhtmlrenderer

XHTML:

```
    <span style="color:#696969;">
        <span style="font-family:tahoma;">
            <span style="font-size:8pt;">
                18F, Mirae Asset CENTER1 West Tower
            </span>
        </span>
    </span>
```

converted document.xml:

```
<w:r>
       <w:rPr>
            <w:rFonts w:ascii="Tahoma" w:hAnsi="Tahoma"/>
            <w:b w:val="false"/>
            <w:i w:val="false"/>
            <w:color w:val="696969"/>
       </w:rPr>
       <w:t>
           18F, Mirae Asset CENTER1 West Tower
       </w:t>
</w:r>
```

`font-size:8pt;` not getting converted to `<w:sz w:val="8"/>` in ooxml.
If font-size is given as small,x-large,etc. it gets converted.

Answer (score 0):

You'd expect it to get converted as w:val=16 since the measurement is in half points.  https://github.com/plutext/docx4j/blob/master/docx4j-core/src/main/java/org/docx4j/model/properties/run/FontSize.java#L123

Comment: So font-size in pts gets ignored it seems. Tried using px by converting pt to px

Comment: Does xhtml to docx converter reads inline CSS or external CSS files ? Was not able to get that working as well. Tried adding classes in `XhtmlNamespaceHandler.css`  file, but didn't work. Renderer used is `xhtmlrenderer-3.0.0.jar`

Comment: It uses FlyingSaucer, which supports both embedded and linked CSS, so if you are having issues, see for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25990886/external-css-in-flying-saucer